# Are there materials that get softer with temperature decrease?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, material-science, crystals, soft-matter

Could be there material that begins melting/softening when it's temperature is lowered?
I would say no, but I've seen enough physics to know that not always life is so easy.

Moreover I think I've heard something about it, but can't remember a thing.

Comment: Nothing melts when the temperature is lowered, but a solid material with a negative coefficient of thermal expansion might theoretically get softer

Comment: @Jim would a negative CTE imply it softens? Or just that it expands as it cools? Maybe the two are correlated, I've never really thought about it...

Comment: @tpg2114 I wouldn't say it implies that it softens, but I can't imagine anything that gets softer as it contracts. The only time I can imagine something getting softer is also when it expands (allows more cushioning of each molecule/atom), so I said negative CTE

Comment: @Jim I have the same intuition but since expanding in my head is usually accompanied by more degrees of freedom due to increased energy, I'm having trouble separating the two concepts... I'd be very interested to see a question and answer about the relationship between stiffness and CTE

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat Thanks. At least when left with no answer I can make an experiment.

Comment: Anyway, that's probably a wild-goose chase, as it is probably related to different substances separating or mixing at different temperatures. So, not really _one_ "material", I suppose.

Comment: Not quite what you asked, but silicone foam rubber will harden ("age") when heated - but this is not a reversible process, so "begin softening when temperature is lowered" is not true. See http://www.foams.saint-gobain.com/uploadedFiles/SGfoams/Documents/COHRlastic%20Brochure.pdf , table on page 4.

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat My experience with crust is the same. It's crispy when freshly from the bakery, then softens, but crispyness is restored after putting it in the oven.
Since the word "material" contains "composite material" I can say that there are more materials satisfying the conditions from my question.
But how do we call them?

Comment: The crust going soft relates to absorption of moisture (evaporating from inside the bread) followed by drying out (as the insides have cooled down and stop supplying moisture). I think that changes the material - it's "crust plus bread" not just "crust" any more.

Comment: It appears you should/may rephrase 'material' to '[chemical substance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_substance)'. This rules out mixtures. I think.

Comment: What do you mean by "softens" in this context? increased compressibility? The opposite of mineral hardness?

Comment: @ColinMcFaul I think about the opposite of hardness specified here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardness
Especially about indentation hardness.

Comment: I would suggest fixing the question (defining or replacing 'softness', 'material') and having it migrated to Chemistry SE. Surely it belongs there.

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat I'll  wait two days and then use your advice.

Answer (score 4):

Materials that exhibit entropic elasticity will theoretically exhibit this effect. For example, elastomers that at a temperature far greater than the glass transition temperature.

In entropic elasticity, stiffness arises not from stretching mechanical bonds, but by decreasing the entropy of the polymer chains in the material. A derivation of this phenomenon is beyond the scope of this question, but here's the punchline:

**The initial shear modulus of the material is proportional to the absolute temperature.** This fits the bill for a material that "softens when it gets colder."

Here is a link to the Wikipedia page for rubber elasticity. This phenomenon is described in more detail here.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_elasticity

Answer (score 3):

You may wish to google "retrograde melting" - some allows/mixtures do melt with cooling. See, e.g., http://xraysweb.lbl.gov/uxas/Publicatons/Papers/pdfs/hudelson%20adv%20mat.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There's a nitinol wire that stiffens when warm and softens when cool.
It's been used in various patented heat engine applications. see this reference http://www.imagesco.com/articles/nitinol/09.html